# Having trouble with my first for loop which counts the number of times row of X dataframe exists in Y dataframe

Tags: r

I have these two dataframes:

```
   df1<-structure(list(Measures = c("space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "space and shape", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "uncertainty and data", 
    "change and relationships", "quantity", "quantity", "uncertainty and data", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "quantity", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "quantity", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "space and shape", "change and relationships", "quantity", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "change and relationships", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships"), Format = c("Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Auto-coded", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Complex Multiple Choice"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -109L), class = "data.frame")
    






   df2<- structure(list(Measures = c("space and shape", "space and shape", 
"space and shape", "space and shape"), Format = c("Constructed Response Expert", 
"Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I use this code to subset all the rows of first dataframe which are present in second dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(df1, df2)
```

But i also want to **count** the number of rows which are available in first dataframe for each row of df2 and store these counts in a vector. This is a little hard to explain with words so i made a short video to explain:

https://youtu.be/gxIaNxSXSUM

i tried doing it on my own and created a for loop to do this. This is the first time ever i have actually used a loop and it failed miserably:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {  
    b<- data.frame('NA','NA')
    b[i,]<- inner_join(df1, df2[i,])
    num[i]<- nrow(b)
}
```

When i print num i get

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` is this what you were looking for?

````r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- 
  df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, keep = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Measures.y, Format.y) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

``` r

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   Measures.y [2]
#>   Measures.y      Format.y                            n
#>   <chr>           <chr>                           <int>
#> 1 space and shape Constructed Response Auto-coded     2
#> 2 space and shape Constructed Response Expert         9
#> 3 space and shape Constructed Response Manual         6
#> 4 space and shape Simple Multiple Choice              6
#> 5 <NA>            <NA>                               86
````

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Following additional comment; to view cases where there are no instances in df2 the code could be adapted:

```
df <- 
  df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, keep = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Measures.x, Format.x, Measures.y, Format.y) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(n = if_else(is.na(Measures.y), 0L, n))
```

Comment: The only issue with this code is that it does not display if 0 of something are present in df1

Comment: The group by measures.x and format.x just gave me a dataframe which shows how many of each type of item are present in df1. Its not relating it to df2. I dont see any zeroes. if i have a row in df2 which is not present in df1 then it should show up as n=0.

Comment: Updated answer is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!!!!!!!! youre awesome peter

Comment: Hey peter could you elaborate on the last statement mutate(n = if_else(is.na(Measures.y), 0L, n)) . I am having trouble understandig it. I read the help of mutate and i did not see any argument called 'n'.

Comment: n is a variable created in the call to summarise in the previous line, it is the count of the number of instances in each group defined in the call to `group_by`. The mutate call modifies or mutates the variable `n` with an if-else condition: if `Measures.y ` is NA then change the value of `n` to zero or more precisely the integer zero else leave the value as `n`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. n is not an argument but just the name of the column. I could have used anything in place of n such as 'y'. I could also use the count() function to do the same. But we want to do some data manipulation on 'y' later in mutate which is why we specify it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a loop, one strategy could be to count the groups in `df1` prior to your `inner_join`. One approach might look like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  count(across(everything())) %>% 
  inner_join(df2)

#> Joining, by = c("Measures", "Format")
#>          Measures                          Format n
#> 1 space and shape Constructed Response Auto-coded 1
#> 2 space and shape     Constructed Response Expert 2
#> 3 space and shape     Constructed Response Manual 1
#> 4 space and shape          Simple Multiple Choice 1
```

I took a subset of df1 since it's pretty big:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(
    Measures = c(
      "space and shape",
      "space and shape",
      "space and shape",
      "space and shape",
      "space and shape",
      "change and relationships"
    ),
    Format = c(
      "Constructed Response Expert",
      "Constructed Response Manual",
      "Constructed Response Expert",
      "Simple Multiple Choice",
      "Constructed Response Auto-coded",
      "Constructed Response Expert"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

df2 <- structure(list(
  Measures = c(
    "space and shape",
    "space and shape",
    "space and shape",
    "space and shape"
  ),
  Format = c(
    "Constructed Response Expert",
    "Constructed Response Manual",
    "Simple Multiple Choice",
    "Constructed Response Auto-coded"
  )
),
row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is perfect. But i was also hoping if this was possible with for loop and where did i go wrong.

Comment: What is across doing here?

Comment: Regarding a for loop, it's certainly possible using a combination of group + split + applying some counting function. Regarding across, it's a relatively new function for applying some operation across multiple columns. It supersedes functions like summarise_at/if/all, src: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html.

Comment: what exactly in this code tells R to sort counts by rows?

Comment: If i use count(df1) i get '109' which is number of rows. If i use count(df1, across(everything())) i get counts sorted by common rows. But everything just selects all COLUMNS, and accross just applies counts over all columns??? How is row coming into picture here i am a little confused

Comment: Regarding sorting by count. Nothing in my code is doing any sorting, if you need that you can provide `sort = TRUE` in the `count()` call. Regarding `everything()`, you are correct, it selects everything. If you only need a couple columns counted, you could select those columns, call `distinct()` to remove duplication and then count.

Comment: I edited a picture at the end of my question. the code i entered groups(not sorts i guess my english is a little bad) by counts for similar rows.

Comment: nevermind i understood it